# java8 changing from imperative to functional

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

following is my the imperative style of code

```
for (int i = 1; i <= sundayOpenAreas.size(); i++) {
    String area = sundayOpenAreas.get(i - 1);
    String postcode = "XX" + i + " 1AA";

    boolean sundayDeliveryAvailable = sundayDeliveryAvailable(area, postcode);
    Assert.assertTrue(sundayDeliveryAvailable, area + " should accept deliveries on Sunday to " + postcode + "!");
    System.out.println(area + ", " + postcode);
}
```

would like to convert to functional style java8 streams , and following is what tried so far

```
 IntStream.range(0, sundayOpenAreas.size())
        .forEach(
                idx -> {
                    sundayOpenAreas.stream()
                            .map(x -> "XX" + idx + "".concat("1AA"))
                            //Struck here on how to proceed
                    //System.out.println(abc);
                });
```

where `sundayOpenAreas is List<String>`

Comment: is `sundayOpenAreas` a map?

Comment: @jobin: List<String> sundayOpenAreas

Comment: @SasiKathimanda Update your question instead of putting more infos into comments please.

Comment: @Jobin If it would be a map, how could the "old school" code go for .get() on it?!

Comment: You may first want to reverse the list using `Collections.reverse()` (and create `AreaWithPostcode` class before, because you need original indexes and naming an enitity is a better option)
Also notice that if `List` do not implements `RandomAccess` it would be a performance bottleneck, cause for example `LinkedList.get(index)` is `O(N)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I think you should stick to your imperative approach, because you need multiple variables in the pipeline.

I would give this a try:

```
IntStream.range(0, sundayOpenAreas.size())
    .mapToObj(i -> new String[] { sundayOpenAreas.get(i), "XX" + i + " 1AA" })
    .peek(s -> Assert.assertTrue(sundayDeliveryAvailable(s[0], s[1]),
        s[0] + " should accept deliveries on Sunday to " + s[1] + "!"))
    .forEachOrdered(s -> System.out.println(s[0] + ", " + s[1]));
```

Comment: sundayDeliveryAvailable(area, postcode); is changed to sundayDeliveryAvailable(s[0], s[1]) , thought it would more readable in functional style.

Comment: @SasiKathimanda As I said, you should stick to your imperative solution.

Comment: Ok, so in my imperative solution i can't avoid shared mutability (state) ?

Comment: @SasiKathimanda What do you mean by "avoiding shared mutability (state)"?

Comment: String area = sundayOpenAreas.get(i - 1);
    String postcode = "XX" + i + " 1AA"; contains state at specific time frame and if i need to run it parallel i cannot do it.

Comment: @SasiKathimanda It isn't a mutable state since the data is only valid and created in one iteration. You can perfectly parallelize the `Stream` pipeline I've given to you because there are no side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which you can try:

```
IntStream.of(sundayOpenAreas.size())
                    .filter(i -> {
                        String postcode = "XX" + i + " 1AA";
                        return sundayDeliveryAvailable(String.valueOf(i), postcode);
                    })
                    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: sorry think i haven't followed here: where should i use Assert statement?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    IntStream.range(0, sundayOpenAreas.size())
    .forEach(idx -> {
        sundayOpenAreas.stream()
        .map(x -> "XX" + idx + "".concat("1AA"))
        .filter(x -> sundayDeliveryAvailable(sundayOpenAreas.get(idx), x)).forEach(System.out::println);
    });
```